# App's communication with remote servers in iOS according to AppStore Rules

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am creating a WhoIs application which users can get detailed information about a website. My App connects to my server (using NSURLConnection) and gets the information from a PHP page in the server.
I don't encrypt data while sending because it doesn't contain any private information about user.
Is it OK for AppStore Review Guideline or should I do something? There is no information about this in Apple Documents.

Comment: That is entirely up to you and fine the way you draft it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is acceptable. As long as you are not handling private information over an open connection, you will have no problem with the Apple review.

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe your approach is absolutely fine and in compliance with the guidelines.

I recommend you take a look at [WhoAPI](http://whoapi.com/), they provide a RESTful API to get data on domains and servers.

I also highly recomend using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (it is built on top of `NSURLConnection`).

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) makes interacting with APIs a breeze and allows you to properly decouple your networking code from the rest of your app.